# SQL server Database back Up Failed - write failure on backup device

Tags: database, backup-sqldatabase

I am getting below error while taking DB back up. This error occurred  after 55% of complete database backup process. Please provide solution to resolve this issue.

> BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: write failure on backup device '\networkpath\MYDB.BAK'. Operating system error 1(Incorrect function.).

using below script for DB back up:-

```
BACKUP DATABASE PolarisPROD TO DISK = '\\networkpath\MYDB.BAK' WITH INIT
```

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure. What makes you think it's software?

Comment: But on Same Db server, Point in time DB back up completed.

Comment: Just to update, I was managed to take full back up by connecting Management Studio using SA account. But i was getting above error when i was taking DB back up from my Windows Service Application. I think it is credentials issue. Not sure as of now.